# What is the correct HTML syntax for adding an ID to a tbody element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get the values from API using JS and create a DIV tag with Table Rows.The rows and data are formed successfully. The problem is that when I call this inside a Table BODY it does not work. The Data are visible outside the Table.

```
$.each(data.tasks, function(i,tasks)
    {
        j=j+1;
        var html ="<tr><td>"+j+"</td><td>"+data.tasks[j].song_name+"</td><td>"+data.tasks[j].album_name+"</td><td>"+data.tasks[j].price+"</td></tr>";
        $(html).appendTo("#odersList");
    });
```

And my HTML code is:

```
 <tbody>
 <div id="odersList"></div>
 </tbody>
```

Comment: That is not valid markup.

Comment: This is totally invalid. Also, why would you want to nest a div to a table structure???

Comment: What is the idea behind needing a `<div>` that can't be achieved by using ID on `<tbody>`?

Comment: <table><`here`><tr><`here`><td><`valid`></td><`here`></tr><`here`></table> all places marked as <here> are invalid zones of putting any html element other than table properties that might apply.

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks a lot. Adding the ID to the tbody worked. But I want to add two more rows at the last which is static but is appearing in the starting. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: use a `<tfoot>` after `<tbody>`. Also can have multiple `<tbody>`

Comment: The only allowed direct child element of `tbody` is `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

Do like below :

```
$.each(data.tasks, function(i,tasks)
    {
        j=j+1;
        var html ="<table><tbody><tr><td>"+j+"</td><td>"+data.tasks[j].song_name+"</td><td>"+data.tasks[j].album_name+"</td><td>"+data.tasks[j].price+"</td></tr></tbody></table>";
        $(html).appendTo("#odersList");
    });
```

and HTML markup

```
     <div id="odersList"></div>
```

Because the markup ou are using is invalid, you can't add Div tag in `<tbody>` but you can add it in `<td>`

Answer (score 0):

Adding id to the TBODY worked.

```
<tbody id="odersList">
```